# unique fields with size issue

Tags: mysql, unique

I've got a mysql database and I'm trying to put a url and unique id into two seperate fields.
One of the urls are sometimes more than 800 characters long. 
I tried to create a UNIQUE index of the id and url, so that I'm not linking to the same url/id combo more than once, but I get an error regarding field length for the index.

I'm currently storing the url as a varchar. should I maybe be using blog? or something else? how will that effect the UNIQUE index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep URL in a `TEXT` field, keep the `MD5` hash of the URL in another column, and create a unique index on the hash column.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the size limit on varchar is 255.  You should change from type varchar to text.